# ASP.Net Error - Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, casting, asp.net-session

I get the below error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

This is the code I'm using

Dim str As String = String.Empty

```
    If (Session("Brief") IsNot Nothing) Then

        Dim dt As DataTable = Session("Brief")
        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If (str.Length > 0) Then str += ","
                str += dr("talentID").ToString()
            Next
        End If

    End If

    Return str
```

Thanks

Comment: Its an aside... but Can I ask why you are storing an entire datatable in the session, and  what kind of session state are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a VB guy, but I would have thought you would need to cast the session variable to the correct type (DataTable):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Session("Brief"), DataTable);
```

Comment: What error did you get - the same one? Are you sure that that session variable actually contains a DataTable object?

Comment: @xtrabits, which line throws the exception? This one?: Dim dt As DataTable = Session("Brief")

Comment: Get the type of the object by writing this Session("Brief").GetType().ToString(), make sure it is a DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to "cast" Session("Brief") :

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Session("Brief"), Datatable)
```

see example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.sortcommand(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
Dim str As String = ""

If Not Session("Brief") Is Nothing Then
  Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(Session("Brief"), DataTable)

  If Not dt Is Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
      If (str.Length > 0) Then
        str += ","
      End If

      str += dr("talentID").ToString()
    Next
  End If
End If

Return str
```

Use TryCast and the check of the cast was succesful or not...

And here's version with a bit of LINQ thrown in for good measure:

```
Dim str As String = ""

If Not Session("Brief") Is Nothing Then
  Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(Session("Brief"), DataTable)

  If Not dt Is Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    str = Join((From r In dt Select CStr(r("talentID"))).ToArray, ",")
  End If
End If

Return str
```

Comment: Another option to determine if Session("Brief") is a DataTable (instead of using TryCast) would be to use VB's TypeOf operator:

If TypeOf Session("Brief") Is DataTable Then ...